# What is the correct time format for std::time_get::get_time() in locale "en_US"?

Tags: c++, locale

In `locale("en_US")` I cannot read time by `std::time_get::get_time()`.
I tried the following format but it does not work.
When I change the locale to `locale("en_GB")` it works well.
So What is the correct time format for in locale "en_US" ?

The source is:

```
void try_get_time_from_str(const std::string& s) {
    std::istringstream str(s);
    std::ios_base::iostate err = std::ios_base::goodbit;
    std::tm t;
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> ret =
        std::use_facet<std::time_get<char> >(str.getloc()).get_time(
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(str),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
            str, err, &t
        );
    str.setstate(err);
    if(str) {
        std::cout << "Hours: "   << t.tm_hour << ' '
                  << "Minutes: " << t.tm_min  << ' '
                  << "Seconds: " << t.tm_sec  << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed. Unparsed string: ";
        std::copy(ret, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                  std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout));
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US"));
    try_get_time_from_str("01:01:01");
    try_get_time_from_str("1:01:01");
    try_get_time_from_str("1:1:1");
    try_get_time_from_str("01:01");
    try_get_time_from_str("1:01");
    try_get_time_from_str("1:1");
    try_get_time_from_str("01:01:01 PM");
    try_get_time_from_str("1:01:01 PM");
    try_get_time_from_str("1:1:1 PM");
    try_get_time_from_str("01:01 PM");
    try_get_time_from_str("1:01 PM");
    try_get_time_from_str("1:1 PM");
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
Parse failed. Unparsed string: 01:01:01
Parse failed. Unparsed string: 1:01:01
Parse failed. Unparsed string: 1:1:1
Parse failed. Unparsed string: 01:01
Parse failed. Unparsed string: 1:01
Parse failed. Unparsed string: 1:1
Parse failed. Unparsed string: 01:01:01 PM
Parse failed. Unparsed string: 1:01:01 PM
Parse failed. Unparsed string: 1:1:1 PM
Parse failed. Unparsed string: 01:01 PM
Parse failed. Unparsed string: 1:01 PM
Parse failed. Unparsed string: 1:1 PM
```

I've tried output a time in `locale("en_US")` with format "%X", the result is "10:27:06 AM".
And the doc says that the default format is "%X" for `std::time_get::get_time()`, but it can't be read indeed.

PS: I use g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) on LINUX.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to help — my OS doesn't support locales very well — but why not use `en_US` to print a time and see what comes out?

Comment: @Potatoswatter I've tried to print a time in `en_US`, it looks like normally ("10:27:06 AM"), so...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a compiler bug. Having g++ 4.72 and running:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

void try_get_time_from_str(const std::string& s) {
    std::istringstream str(s);
    std::ios_base::iostate err = std::ios_base::goodbit;
    std::tm t;
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> ret =
        std::use_facet<std::time_get<char> >(str.getloc()).get_time(
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(str),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
            str, err, &t
        );
    str.setstate(err);
    if(str) {
        std::cout << "Hours: "   << t.tm_hour << ' '
                  << "Minutes: " << t.tm_min  << ' '
                  << "Seconds: " << t.tm_sec  << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed. Unparsed string: ";
        std::copy(ret, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                  std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout));
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::time_t timestamp;
    std::time ( &timestamp );
    std::tm * now = std::localtime ( &timestamp );
    std::cout <<  "GB: ";
    {
        std::locale::global(std::locale("en_GB.utf8"));
        std::ostringstream out;
        std::use_facet< std::time_put<char> >(out.getloc()).put(
            out,
            out,
            ' ',
            now,
            'X');
        try_get_time_from_str(out.str());
    }
    std::cout <<  "US: ";
    {
        std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
        std::ostringstream out;
        std::use_facet< std::time_put<char> >(out.getloc()).put(
            out,
            out,
            ' ',
            now,
            'X');
        try_get_time_from_str(out.str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

gives:

```
GB: Hours: 14 Minutes: 59 Seconds: 53
US: Parse failed. Unparsed string: 02:59:53 PM
```